# Scraping an iframe with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape this site: https://www.mercedes-benz.de/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/dealer-locator.html

What's the best way here to refer to an element (e.g. aggregated number or mercedes dealer) within the map in a way that I would be able to iterate through all of them afterwards? So storing all the objects within a list and iterate through that list.

The mercedes dealers are stored here in a class called "leaflet-marker-icon dl-dealer-marker leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-interactive" whereas the aggregation numbers are stored in the class "leaflet-marker-icon dl-marker-cluster leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-interactive". I tried to do it with

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "dl-marker-cluster")]')
```

Ended up with the error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all those elements and just loop em. You'd do something like this. You need to handle the popup and then go into the iframe.

```
driver.get("https://www.mercedes-benz.de/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/dealer-locator.html")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'dlc-cont')))
elems=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'dl-marker-cluster')]")))
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: So this didn't work for me somehow :/ Anyway. I solved it with iterating through all german postal codes. But there is one thing left: Do you have an idea how I could make sure that the element with xpath: "/html/body/div[1]/dlc/div/div/section[2]/section" (that is the dealer list on the left side) shows always all the dealers without the need of always scrolling the list till its end manually? You can see what I mean when typing in a postal code (e.g. '91281') and choose 50km as radius. In order to get all dealers into the list you have to scroll down. How to force the list to show everything

Comment: Solved it with ActionChains :) Thanks for helping out!